# How to print the ARM assembly instructions before they are executed in Android?

Tags: android, dalvik

In Android 4.3 according to the [source code documentation](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/dalvik/vm/mterp/), the Dalvik interpreter is located in dalvik/vm/mterp/ but how can I print the ARM assembly instructions before they are executed at runtime?

**Note:**

Assume the JIT compiler is off and we only need to print the ARM assembly instructions from the interpreter (or after the interpretation process).

Comment: You want to disassemble the Dalvik VM?

Comment: No. I want to print apps ARM assembly instructions before they are executed on the CPU.

Comment: There is no mechanism to do this on a real device. The very act of trying to print the instructions would cause more instructions to be executed. However, you might be able to do this in the qemu (the arm emulator used to run Android emulators in the Android SDK)

Comment: Each VM opcode (http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html, https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html) consists of multiple ARM instructions (assuming you're targeting ARM, obviously). That's what a VM does: runs a *virtual* CPU. It's still not clear to me exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I am running the Android on a Linux PC and I think I can change the Android source code to print anything. I just need to know where in the Android source code can I put the print statements to print apps ARM assembly instructions before they are executed on the CPU